# Bash Scripting (Linux)

Tags: linux, bash

I have to greet my users with a small message:
The greeting should display a " good morning, good afternoon and good evening depending on the time of day.

My code (associated with the time) is not fully working, as it always displays"good evening", any obvious mistakes that i am not spotting?

```
echo "please enter a username:" 
read username

username=$(getent passwd "$USER" |cut -d ':' -f 5 | ',' -f 1)
echo "Welcome $username" | cat >> output.txt

current_data_time = "'date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S'";
echo $current_data_time;

TIME=$(date +H")
hours= date +"%H | sed -e 's/^0/g'

if [ $TIME -lt 12 ]; then
echo "Good morning $username"
elif [ $TIME -lt 18 ]]; then
echo "Good afternoon $username"
else
echo "Good evening $username"
fi
```

Comment: try `getent passwd "$USER"` ...

Comment: Try to run the script first, look at the errors you get, and fix them. There are a couple of places where the script contains an obvious typo of something you've used elsewhere in the script.

Comment: Please see [mcve] and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A StackOverflow question should be focused on a single, specific problem, with anything unrelated to that problem removed. Here, you've got a whole bunch of code unrelated to whatever's going wrong, and no description of what it is that's going wrong present in the question at all.

Comment: as an aside, where is this exercise from?

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unterminated `s' command
practice.sh: 18: [: Illegal number: H
practice.sh: 20: [: Illegal number: H, these are the errors i recieve, the name works as it appears with " good evening (name) " however there is something wrong with the time.

Comment: Also pertinent: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/14122). Questions derived from homework *are* allowed here, but are expected to conform to the same standards of quality as any other question.

Comment: @BiologyBlooper, ...now, that's a fine problem (though if you looked at the syntax for replacements with `sed` in the manual, you might figure its cause out yourself). A good question centered around that problem would remove anything unrelated to it (for instance, as you indicated above that you already know the name extraction is fine, there's no need to include any of that code here), and call out the specific issue with the `sed` expression in the question's title.

Comment: You might also make a practice of fixing any issue that http://shellcheck.net/ can find before asking about code here.

Comment: The script as presented above will not even execute `sed` (there's a syntax error preventing it from getting to that). As it's written above, you should get a couple of `command not found` errors, though. I really suggest presenting the script exactly if you want anyone to be able to spot the actual errors.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the link to shellcheck.net that will be of use to me.

Comment: @BiologyBlooper Instead of *Thanks*, you could upvote the comment! (Interesting, I've already upvoted them;)

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun...

```
hope=(morning{,} afternoon evening)
printf -v hrclass "%(%H)T/6" -1

read -p 'Please, enter your username: ' userinput
IFS=: read -r user pass uid gid name home shell < <(getent passwd $userinput)

if [ "$user" ] && [ "$user" = "$userinput" ]; then
    echo Good ${hope[hrclass]} ${name//,}
else
    echo "Unknown user:" $userinput
fi
```

No explanation: I will let you read the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)'s man page (`man bash`) and work to understand each steps. (Nota this use bash and so called *bashisms*.)... Maybe another day, if really comments ask for. But today, I have to go...